# ¿Como usar un campo generado en la fase anterior

Tags: mongodb, sql, agregación

Hola estoy aprendiendo MongoDB así que agradecería la ayuda:
Quisiera saber si al realizar las fases de una agregación, en una fase puedo acceder al contenido generado en la fase anterior. He intentado lo siguiente pero no me ha funcionado. En las fases 0 y 1 con el código

```
var fase0 = { "$group" : { "_id": null,  "reciente" : { "$max" : "$year"} } }
var fase1= { "$project": { "_id" : 0 } }
var etapas= [ fase0, fase1]
db.peliculas.aggregate( etapas )
```

obtengo el año más reciente de la base de datos.

```
{ 
    "reciente" : NumberInt(2000)
}
```

Ahora me gustaría modificar el código para que cogiera el valor de "reciente" automáticamente en la siguiente fase y le restara un entero como por ejemplo 20

```
var fase0 = { "$group" : { "_id": null,  "reciente" : { "$max" : "$year"} } }
var fase1= { "$project": { "_id" : 0 } }
// Usar el valor de "reciente" para obtener los elementos que cumplen que el año> (reciente-20)
// en el ejemplo año>1980 
var fase2= { "$match" : { "year": {"$gt": { "$subtract": ["reciente", 20] } }}}
var fase3= { "$group" : { "_id": null,  "count" : { "$sum" : 1} } }
var etapas= [ fase0,fase1,fase2, fase3]
db.peliculas.aggregate(etapas )
```

Sin embargo, al hacer la agregación no me devuelve nada

Comment: Gracias, ya lo he editado

Comment: Podrias actualizar tu pregunta con el documento que obtienes de las dos primeras fases?